# AHK, not working as expected

Tags: autohotkey

trying to make a toggle-able loop, seems to be not sending e at all, help please?

```
myvar := false
k::
myvar := true ? false : true
return
while (myvar)
{
Send, e
Sleep 100
}
```

Comment: to be clear, the behavoir i was trying to create is; do nothing, k is pressed, repeatedly send e until k is pressed again.

Comment: Check your ternery operator.

Comment: see edit below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can assign another key to pause / resume. In this case k will toggle and F12 will run indefinitely (so just use k to toggle).

```
k::
Hotkey, F12, toggle
return

F12::
while(true)
{
    Send, e
    Sleep 100
}
```

Could also try `Loop` instead of `while(true)`

```
k::
pause, toggle

F12::
Loop,
{
    Send e
    Sleep, 100
}
return
```

---

referenced from [AutoHotkey forum](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60321-how-to-toggle-script-onoff-with-a-key/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
k::SetTimer, SendLetterE, % (Toggle:=!Toggle) ? 100 : "Off"

SendLetterE() {
    Send, e
}
```

Comment: Much better answer than the selected one. This definitely should have been the accepted answer. This is clean and done in 4 lines. The other is a bit more sloppy, uses unnecessary commands, uses 2 hotkeys and one answer suggests using "pause" as the start/stop. Not the best choice. :-/